# Be careful when using T-Sql IN operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyone to explain that why this kind of queries running like where id_t1=id_t1 because of IN operator?

My colleague deleted whole table rows even though he wanted to delete some rows, when we analyzed query we realized that there is a problem using "IN" operator. Query structure was not proper but it ran.
I want to show this stuation how to become:

```
create table #table1(id_t1 int)
create table #table2(id_t2 int)

--insert data
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(1)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(2)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(3)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(4)

insert into #table2(id_t2) values(10)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(20)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(30)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(40)
```

as you can see there is no **id_t1** in **#table2**, 
when you run

```
select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10
```

query returns:

```
Invalid column name 'id_t1'.
```

but it can be using with "in" operator

```
select * from #table1 where id_t1 in (select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)
```

it returns whole **#table1** rows

```
id_t1
---------
1
2
3
4
```

when you use for **delete** operation like above

```
delete from #table1 where id_t1 in (select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)
```

**your #table1 have no more rows :)**

```
select * from #table1


id_t1
-----------

(0 row(s)


drop table #table1
drop table #table2
```

---

whole of my sample script to easily copy/paste:

```
create table #table1(id_t1 int)
create table #table2(id_t2 int)

--insert data
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(1)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(2)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(3)
insert into #table1(id_t1) values(4)

insert into #table2(id_t2) values(10)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(20)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(30)
insert into #table2(id_t2) values(40)

select * from #table1 where id_t1 in (select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)


delete from #table1 where id_t1 in (select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)


select * from #table1

drop table #table1
drop table #table2
```

Comment: That is just an example why one should use table alias in any case :-)

Comment: because your in clause does not know, it has to check for that column in #table2, compiler can find it in #table1 hence the result.

Answer (score 4):

In your select query

```
select * from #table1 where id_t1 in (select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)
```

SQL interprets it as

```
select * from #table1 where #table1.id_t1 in (select #table1.id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10)
```

So, for each row in #table1, the `in` clause is the value of #table1.id_t1, repeated for each row of table 2. So of course, every row qualifies.

This is why you should never run a delete statement without checking the select first...

Answer (score 3):

that is because id_t1 does exists in table1 and in your where you did not say that id_t1 has to come from the correct table.
Using an alias for every table can solve this problem very easy.

This would be better

```
select * 
from   #table1 t1 
where  t1.id_t1 in (select t2.id_t1 from #table2 t2 where t2.id_t2 = 10)
```

now you get `Invalid column name id_t1` like you expected

Answer (score 0):

Sub query

```
select id_t1 from #table2  where id_t2 = 10
```

will return column `Id_t1` of `#Table1` corresponding, so condition `IN` always matched.

The correct query should be

```
select * 
from #table1 where id_t1 in 
                          (select t2.id_t2 from #table2 t2  where t2.id_t2 = 10)
```

Or using `EXIST`

```
select * from #table1 t1 
where Exist (select t2.id_t2 from #table2 t2  where t2.id_t2 = 10 and t2.id_t2 = t1.id_t1)
```

Or using `INNER JOIN`

```
select * 
from #table1 t1
inner join #table2 t2 on t1.id_t1 = t2.id_t2
where t2.id_t2 = 10
```

Logic is same when delete